# Docusign Trigger is not firing

Tags: trigger, docusign

I have Docusign plugin integrated to the Salesforce account.

The requirement is to make a callout to external website to send some SMS etc when Docusign Recipient Status has its status either "Delivered" or "Completed"

I have written the test class for this and code coverage is also 100%.

The problem is the trigger is not getting fired all the times. Its only getting fired very few times.

Here is the trigger code.

```
trigger DocuSignRecipientStatus on dsfs__DocuSign_Recipient_Status__c (after insert,after update) {
    if (Trigger.isInsert) {

        for(dsfs__DocuSign_Recipient_Status__c docuSignStatus : Trigger.New) {  

            if ( 
                ( docuSignStatus.dsfs__Recipient_Status__c == 'Delivered' ) ||
                ( docuSignStatus.dsfs__Recipient_Status__c == 'Completed' )
            ) {

                Id leadId = docuSignStatus.dsfs__Lead__c;           
                Lead rLead = [SELECT Name, Phone, Email, Business_Name__c, Owner.Id FROM Lead WHERE Id = :leadId];                               

                Id leadOwnerId = rLead.Owner.Id;
                User leadOwner = [SELECT Phone, MobilePhone FROM User WHERE Id = :leadOwnerId];

                // Here I make a String Map with some values and make a callout.   

            }

        }

    }
}
```

And here is the test class

```
@isTest
public class DocuSignRecipientStatusTest {
    @isTest static void testMakeCurlRequest() {

        StaticResourceCalloutMock mock = new StaticResourceCalloutMock();
        mock.setStaticResource('calloutmock');
        mock.setStatusCode(200);

        Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, mock);

        Profile userProfile = [SELECT Id FROM Profile WHERE Name = 'Standard User'];

        User leadOwner = new User (
            Username = 'ttttestusername@gmail.com',            
            Alias='tdummy22',
            Email='lllleadowneremail@gmail.com',            
            CommunityNickname='tttestnickname',
            LastName='dddummy',            
            MobilePhone='06646465465',
            Phone='05546465465',
            EmailEncodingKey='ISO-8859-1',
            ProfileId=userProfile.Id,
            LocaleSidKey='en_US',
            LanguageLocaleKey='en_US',
            TimeZoneSidKey='America/New_York'
        );

        insert leadOwner;

        Lead docusignLead = new Lead(            
            FirstName='TestFirstName',
            LastName='TestLastName',
            Phone='05646465465',            
            Email='testemail@gmail.com',            
            Business_Name__c='testbusinessname',
            Company='test company',
            OwnerId=leadOwner.Id
        );
        insert docusignLead;

        dsfs__DocuSign_Status__c docusignParentStatus = new dsfs__DocuSign_Status__c(
            dsfs__Lead__c=docusignLead.Id,
            dsfs__Sender__c='docusign sender',
            dsfs__Sender_Email__c='someemail@gmail.com',
            dsfs__Subject__c='some subject',
            dsfs__Envelope_Status__c='some status'
        );

        insert docusignParentStatus;

        dsfs__DocuSign_Recipient_Status__c newDocusignStatus = new dsfs__DocuSign_Recipient_Status__c(
            dsfs__Recipient_Status__c='Delivered',            
            Name='testname',
            dsfs__DocuSign_Recipient_Id__c='recipientid',
            dsfs__Lead__c=docusignLead.Id,
            dsfs__Parent_Status_Record__c=docusignParentStatus.Id
        );

        insert newDocusignStatus;

        dsfs__DocuSign_Recipient_Status__c newDocusignCompletedStatus = new dsfs__DocuSign_Recipient_Status__c(
            dsfs__Recipient_Status__c='Completed',            
            Name='testname',
            dsfs__DocuSign_Recipient_Id__c='recipientid',
            dsfs__Lead__c=docusignLead.Id,
            dsfs__Parent_Status_Record__c=docusignParentStatus.Id
        );

        insert newDocusignCompletedStatus;

        Test.startTest();       
        Lead testdocusignLead = [
            SELECT 
                Id, Name, Phone, Email, Business_Name__c, Owner.Id
            FROM 
                Lead 
            WHERE Id=:docusignLead.Id
            LIMIT 1
        ];        
        System.assertEquals(docusignLead.FirstName, 'TestFirstName');                
        System.assertEquals(docusignLead.LastName, 'TestLastName');
        System.assertEquals(docusignLead.Phone, '05646465465');
        System.assertEquals(docusignLead.Email, 'testemail@gmail.com');   
        System.assertEquals(docusignLead.Business_Name__c, 'testbusinessname');        
        System.assertEquals(docusignLead.LastModifiedById, docusignLead.Owner.Id);

        Id leadOwnerId = testdocusignLead.Owner.Id;
        User leadOwnerTest = [SELECT Phone, MobilePhone FROM User WHERE Id = :leadOwnerId];

        System.assertEquals(leadOwnerTest.Phone, '05546465465');
        System.assertEquals(leadOwnerTest.MobilePhone, '06646465465');

        // Callout to the external website

        Test.stopTest();                
    }
}
```

I am really stuck with the firing of Trigger. I am not even sure how to tackle this problem.

Is there any problem with the trigger code ?

Can anyone help ?

Comment: Are you sure trigger is active?

Comment: With what you've provided, your trigger is set up to run `after update`, but you only have code that runs `after insert`. Just to clarify, do you intend for the portion of the trigger you've provided to be run only `after insert`, or should it also be run `after update`?

Comment: you have some conceptual issues (1) callouts can't be done after DML statements in the same transaction - your test method has several inserts so the callouts will fail after the first insert; (2) Structure of an assert is (expected value, actual value) and you have them backwards; (3) The mere act of inserting `dsfs__DocuSign_Recipient_Status__c` will execute the trigger and hence should belong within the `test.startTest` scope; (4) it looks like callouts inside a for loop -- governor problems here

Comment: @itzmukeshy7 Yes, its active, And it works normally - but only very few times, other times, I does not really seem to "fire" the trigger. I wonder, if its something related to the Docusign setting of Salesforce. I have written 5-6 triggers before and have never felt this kind of problem before.

Comment: @DerekF That might be the problem I guess.

Comment: @cropredy Thanks for pointing out these things, I am only a beginner and getting to know Salesforce. I would make sure to check these problems in the code.

Answer (score -1):

Ajeesh , Your trigger code seems fine.

Add a `try/catch` exceptions block to the trigger and write to log using system.debug(e)

Also create another test class like this:
Don't test the `callout` again in  your test class explicitly,you can just used the
`insert newDocusignCompletedStatus;` to test the same

```
@isTest
public class DocuSignRecipientStatusTest {
    @isTest static void testMakeCurlRequest() {

        StaticResourceCalloutMock mock = new StaticResourceCalloutMock();
        mock.setStaticResource('calloutmock');
        mock.setStatusCode(200);

        Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, mock);

        Profile userProfile = [SELECT Id FROM Profile WHERE Name = 'Standard User'];

        User leadOwner = new User (
            Username = 'ttttestusername@gmail.com',            
            Alias='tdummy22',
            Email='lllleadowneremail@gmail.com',            
            CommunityNickname='tttestnickname',
            LastName='dddummy',            
            MobilePhone='06646465465',
            Phone='05546465465',
            EmailEncodingKey='ISO-8859-1',
            ProfileId=userProfile.Id,
            LocaleSidKey='en_US',
            LanguageLocaleKey='en_US',
            TimeZoneSidKey='America/New_York'
        );

        insert leadOwner;

        Lead docusignLead = new Lead(            
            FirstName='TestFirstName',
            LastName='TestLastName',
            Phone='05646465465',            
            Email='testemail@gmail.com',            
            Business_Name__c='testbusinessname',
            Company='test company',
            OwnerId=leadOwner.Id
        );
        insert docusignLead;

        dsfs__DocuSign_Status__c docusignParentStatus = new dsfs__DocuSign_Status__c(
            dsfs__Lead__c=docusignLead.Id,
            dsfs__Sender__c='docusign sender',
            dsfs__Sender_Email__c='someemail@gmail.com',
            dsfs__Subject__c='some subject',
            dsfs__Envelope_Status__c='some status'
        );

        insert docusignParentStatus;

        dsfs__DocuSign_Recipient_Status__c newDocusignStatus = new dsfs__DocuSign_Recipient_Status__c(
            dsfs__Recipient_Status__c='Delivered',            
            Name='testname',
            dsfs__DocuSign_Recipient_Id__c='recipientid',
            dsfs__Lead__c=docusignLead.Id,
            dsfs__Parent_Status_Record__c=docusignParentStatus.Id
        );

        insert newDocusignStatus;

        dsfs__DocuSign_Recipient_Status__c newDocusignCompletedStatus = new dsfs__DocuSign_Recipient_Status__c(
            dsfs__Recipient_Status__c='Completed',            
            Name='testname',
            dsfs__DocuSign_Recipient_Id__c='recipientid',
            dsfs__Lead__c=docusignLead.Id,
            dsfs__Parent_Status_Record__c=docusignParentStatus.Id
        );

        insert newDocusignCompletedStatus;
              
    }
}
```